# Excel Data Manipulation Using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a excel sheet in which column E has all decimal values like 0.5564, 0.87632 and so on.

I want to create a power shell script that selects all these values from E2 till end of the column whatever that row number is dynamically and then multiplies them by 100 and saves the file, so that there is a percentage value in column E instead of a decimal value.

This is my code but this does not work. $worksheet.Range("E2").EntireColumn is not working I believe. Can figure it out also.

PLEASE HELP.

```
$Excelobject=New-object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excelobject.visible = $False
$workbook=$Excelobject.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\OneDrive - Shell\Desktop\Workspacesize.csv")
$worksheet=$workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.Activate()
$worksheet.cells.item(2,1)="Workspace Name"
$data=$worksheet.Range("E2").EntireColumn
foreach ($data in $data){$data=$data*100}
$Excelobject.DisplayAlerts= $False
$workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\OneDrive - Shell\Desktop\Workspacesize.csv")
$workbook.close
$Excelobject.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excelobject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting each Cell's value individually:

```
# Select the Cells with data
$data=$worksheet.Range("E1:E5").Cells | Where Value2
$data | Foreach {
  $_.Value2 = $_.Value2 * 100
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt that be the below?

$data=$worksheet.Range("E1:E5").Cells | Where $_.Value2

Comment: If i execute only this line $worksheet.Range("E2").EntireColumn.Cells | Where-Object Value2 to check what values are being assigned to $data, the values are showing in the console for the last record but then the script is not ending and the code keeps on running.

Comment: @SiddharthaDas Yes, if you specify `EntireColumn`, excel will attempt to process every possible row in the worksheet (millions). You should use the correct range for your data. If your data range has no blank values, then `| Where Value2` is optional (otherwise it will throw a NullReferenceException)

Answer (score 0):

Not as concise as [Cpt.Whale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69377702/9898643), but instead of hardcoding the range "E1:E5", you could have the script determine how many rows it needs to update:

```
$rowMax = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
# I believe you want to skip the first row, otherwise start with `for ($row = 1; ...)`
for ($row = 2; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
    # casting to double here lets $val become 0 on empty cells
    $val = [double]$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 5).Value2
    if ($val) {
        [double]$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, 5).Value2 = $val * 100
    }
}

# close and save the workbook
$workbook.Close($true)
$Excelobject.Quit()
# clean-up used Com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excelobject)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```